# I want to check login for uniqueness by fetch , but it' always typing login is available . Why?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, input, fetch

There are `$result->num_rows` is always `0` in `PHP` code , even though I write `login` that is already in database.

Where I make a mistake ? 
May I've typed some wrong in fetch-query ?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <label >login</label>
    <input name='username' id="input_login" type="text">
    <span id="availability"></span>

    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script> 
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const input_login = document.querySelector("#input_login");
const availability = document.querySelector("#availability");

input_login.onblur = async () => { 
    if(input_login.value != "")   {
    let username = input_login.value;

    const response = await fetch("unique.php", {
        method: 'POST',
        body:{user_name:username}
    })
    const data = await response.text();

    availability.innerHTML =  await data;
}}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "site");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '%".$_POST["user_name"]."%' ";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows < 0) {

  echo 'This username is already taken';
} else {
    echo 'This username is available';
}
```

Comment: The `%` sign is used along the `LIKE` expression. If you're looking for an exact match, delete those.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, it's also a typo `if ($result->num_rows < 0)` will always return FALSEY. You want `>0`.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = ".$_POST["user_name"]." ";
Like what ?

Comment: You're open to sql injection; use a prepared statement.

Comment: `user_name` is not the same as `username`; another typo.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.